# How to insert a set of text to a particular line number of a file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am trying to write a python program that can input a set of text in dictionary format and also a line number. I need to add this set of text to a specific line number of a .yaml file.

I have a Kubernetes deployment.yaml file and I need my Python program to add the text from the dictionary to a particular line number (line 29, **in between cpu: "500m"** and **volumeMounts:**) in the deployment.yaml file.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
      volumeMounts:
      - name: ephemeral
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  volumes:
    - name: ephemeral
      emptyDir: {}
```

**test.py**

```
yaml_change={
  "change": '''
      tolerations:
      - key: "example-key"
        operator: "Exists"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
  '''
}

line_number = 29
yaml_modification = yaml_change['change']

with open('values.yaml', 'r') as FileRead:
    yaml_data = FileRead.readlines()
    yaml_data = yaml_data[line_number-2]+yaml_modification
    print(yaml_data)

with open('values.yaml', 'w') as FileWrite:
    FileWrite.writelines(yaml_data)
```

When I run the python file, the text file in the dictionary gets added to the .yaml file. However, all the other contents are lost.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Does anyone know how to get this requirement done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line `yaml_data = yaml_data[line_number-2]+yaml_modification` to

```
yaml_data.insert(line_number - 1, yaml_modification)
```

`yaml_data` is a list of all lines in the file. The `list.insert(idx, obj)` function inserts the object at a given position.

Your solution doesn't work because you are adding the content you want to add and the line before (`yaml_data[line_number-2]`).